# How to get specific menu item from a custom Wordpress menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to grab a single item from a custom Wordpress menu.

For example, if my menu displays as "Home About Contact", I want to be able to grab just "Home" to generate it elsewhere in the site.

Here is the code I'm using to get the entire menu in the page.

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu( array( 
  'theme_location' => 'left-menu', 
  'container_class' => 'li' ) ); 
?>
```

And here is the custom menu code in the functions.php (if you need it)

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
register_nav_menus(
array(
  'left-menu' => __( 'C3 Left Menu' ),
)
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply just place the menu in the places you wish using `wp_nav_menu`, then use CSS to hide all menu items except the first one?